# ignoring null value columns in python

Tags: python, parsing

I Have a .txt file which has three columns in it.

```
id      ImplementationAuthority.email   AssignedEngineer.email
ALU02034116     bin.a.chen@shan.cn bin.a.chen@ell.com.cn
ALU02035113                                     Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn
ALU02034116     bin.a.chen@ming.com.cn Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn
ALU02022055     fria-sha-qdv@list.com
ALU02030797     fria-che-equipment-1@phoenix.com    Balagopal.Velusamy@phoenix.com
```

I need to create two lists which comprises of values under the column Implementation Authority.mail and Assigned Engineer.mail. It works perfectly when columns have compltete values (i.e no null values). The values got mixed when column contains null values.

```
aengg=[]
iauth=[]

with open('test.txt') as f:
 for i, row in enumerate(f):
  columns = row.split()
  if len(columns) == 3:
   aengg.append(columns[2])
   iauth.append(columns[1])

 print aengg
 print iauth
```

I tried it with this code and it is perfectly worked for complete column values.
Can anyone please tell me a solution for null values?

Comment: Show us first what did you try till now?

Comment: So what is the output now, and what is the expected output. Cant understand. I run your example, and it seems to be working.

Comment: Does your data file use multiple spaces, or tabs to delimit the columns? If the latter, `row.split("\t")` may be all you need. I'd suggest using the `csv` module in any case. I think (but I've not checked) that it can handle arbitrary strings as column separators, so if your file uses multiple spaces, it should be able to adapt.

Comment: What is the definition of a null value? For example both line 3 and 5 consist of an id and a single email address but there needs to be a way to determine whether the email address is meant to be the second or third column.

Comment: null value means the blank space. Those mail id's belongs to appropriate columns above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a separator. I use number of spaces for your case. And fill the blank with a None.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 

aengg = []
iauth = []

with open('C:\\temp\\test.txt') as f:
    for i, row in enumerate(f):
        columns = row.split()
        if len(columns) == 2:
            # when there are more than 17 spaces between two elements, I consider it as a third element in the row, then I add a None between them
            if row.index(columns[1]) > 17:
                columns.insert(1, None)
            # if there are less than 17 spaces between two elements, I consider it as the second element in the row, then I add a None to the tail
            else:
                columns.append(None)
        print columns
        aengg.append(columns[2])
        iauth.append(columns[1])

print aengg
print iauth
```

Here is the output.

```
['id', 'ImplementationAuthority.email', 'AssignedEngineer.email']
['ALU02034116', 'bin.a.chen@shan.cn', 'bin.a.chen@ell.com.cn']
['ALU02035113', None, 'Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn']
['ALU02034116', 'bin.a.chen@ming.com.cn', 'Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn']
['ALU02022055', 'fria-sha-qdv@list.com', None]
['ALU02030797', 'fria-che-equipment-1@phoenix.com', 'Balagopal.Velusamy@phoenix.com']
['AssignedEngineer.email', 'bin.a.chen@ell.com.cn', 'Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn', 'Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn', None, 'Balagopal.Velusamy@phoenix.com']
['ImplementationAuthority.email', 'bin.a.chen@shan.cn', None, 'bin.a.chen@ming.com.cn', 'fria-sha-qdv@list.com', 'fria-che-equipment-1@phoenix.com']
```

Comment: You consider.. its not for everytime.

Comment: @m170897017 Thanks for the code. But i really don't want to append a none and add them to a list. I need to append the appropriate contents into a list.

Comment: @WarriorPrince You can replace None in the code with anything you want. The code doesn't need to change. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @m170897017 I don't want that null entry. If i replace it with it anything then the replaced one will appear in the list which i don't want. Also i tried your code it shows "List index out of Range "

Comment: @WarriorPrince So what do you want to put to replace None? A string?Or?

Answer (score -1):

You need to place a 'null' or 0 as place holder.

The interpreter would read Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn in second row as the second column.

Try this

```
id      ImplementationAuthority.email   AssignedEngineer.email
ALU02034116     bin.a.chen@shan.cn bin.a.chen@ell.com.cn
ALU02035113     null                   Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn
ALU02034116     bin.a.chen@ming.com.cn Guolin.Pan@ell.com.cn
ALU02022055     fria-sha-qdv@list.com  null
ALU02030797     fria-che-equipment-1@phoenix.com    Balagopal.Velusamy@phoenix.com
```

And then append values after checking not null.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
 for i, row in enumerate(f):
  columns = row.split()
  if len(columns) == 3:
   if columns[2] != "null":
    aengg.append(columns[2])
   if columns[1] != "null":
    iauth.append(columns[1])
```

Comment: The file i have given as input is automatically generated one by a tool. Which means it has to be given as direct input without modifying..

Comment: he cant do that if he has a large .txt file.

Comment: Does the spacing have a standard format? Does it have common number of spaces in the output file?